# A relation between a ring with its polynomial ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, abstract-algebra

Let $\{f_i(x)\}_{i\in I}$ be a subset of $R[x]$ where $R[x]$ is the polynomial ring of $R$(a commutative ring with identity). If the ring $R/\langle f_i^2(n)-f_i(n)\rangle_{i\in I, n\in A}$, for every subset $A $ of $ \mathbb{Z} $,
has finitely many idempotent elements. How can we verify that $R[x]/\langle f_i^2(x)-f_i(x)\rangle_{i\in I}$ has finitely many idempotent elements.

Comment: $R=k$ a field, $A$ empty and $I$ infinite with $f_i$ all distinct seems to contradict your conclusion. This is very similar to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225440/an-ideal-generated-by-idempotente-elements , that was closed.

Comment: @MattiaTalpo: It's not because the $f_i$ are all distinct that their images in the quotient are all distinct. Also keep in mind that the ideal $\langle f_i^2(x) - f_i(x) \rangle_{i \in I}$ is a principal ideal (even if $I$ is infinite) when $R=k$ is a field.

Comment: @MattiaTalpo: In fact every quotient of $k[x]$ has finitely many idempotents, so your example is certainly incorrect.

Comment: @TomDeMedts of course, you're right. Also, I had read the 'any subset $A$' not as 'every', but as 'some'...